# Laravel 5.1 & remember me functionality

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

My Laravel 5.1 app keeps the users logged in. I set the variables in session.php like this:

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

I spent a lot of time googling and didn't find any solution. It doesn't matter if I pass "true", "false", or nothing at all as the "remember" parameter for Auth::attempt(). A user will stay logged in after one minute, or after I close the browser. The remember_token gets written into the DB after I log out manually, which seems weird to me.

Doesn't seem to be a browser-specific problem as I checked it in both Firefox and Chromium. Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: I need the session to expire when I close my browser. I set the lifetime to 1 minute just to see if at least that's gonna work and it didn't.

Comment: One minute session sounds useless... would you set 30min or so at least?

Comment: I need the session to expire when I close my browser. I set it to 1 minute just to see if that's gonna make any change, which it didn't

Comment: Tried other browsers and cleared cookies?

Comment: I tried Firefox and Chromium, this should be enough... Clearing cookies is the other way to log a user out besides logging out manually, lol.

Answer (score 0):

If expire_on_close is set to true, laravel will ignore lifetime.

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

and in this case, session is valid after 1 min - it would only expire after closing browser. change it to:

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

and now session will expire after 1 min. no matter if browser is closed or not - closed.

Comment: Well, actually I don't need it to expire after 1 minute. I need it to expire after I close my browser...